# PHP SimpleXML - Read From string

Tags: php, xml

I am using `simplexml_load_string` in PHP. How can I get `numberofrecordings`, `recordingid`, `starttime` and `stoptime` from this array?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [totalnumberofrecordings] => 2
            [numberofrecordings] => 2
        )

    [recording] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [diskid] => SD_DISK
                            [recordingid] => 123123312
                            [starttime] => 2017-05-18T11:40:00.173775Z
                            [starttimelocal] => 2017-05-18T03:40:00.173775-08:00
                            [stoptime] => 2017-05-18T12:15:01.155311Z
                            [stoptimelocal] => 2017-05-18T04:15:01.155311-08:00
                            [recordingtype] => continuous
                            [eventid] => continuous
                            [eventtrigger] => continuous
                            [recordingstatus] => completed
                            [source] => 1
                            [locked] => No
                        )

                )
     )
)
```

Comment: count($array['recording']) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$xml` is your xml object

```
$numberofrecordings = $xml->attributes()->numberofrecordings;
$recordingid = $xml->recording[0]->attributes()->recordingid;
$starttime = $xml->recording[0]->attributes()->starttime;
$stoptime = $xml->recording[0]->attributes()->stoptime;
```